# if statement doesn't work inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I want my picture to go step by step to the left until 1300px with the jobbra button so I have added an if statement to achieve this, but this doesn't work to onlclick. If I delet the if statement the button click function works by itself. What is the problem with my if statement? Thank you

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>PingPongKép</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="ilonakep">
            <img src="/img/ilona.jpg" alt="ilona">
        </div>

        <p id="gombok">

            <button onclick="balra()">Balra</button>

            <button onclick="jobbra()">Jobbra</button>



        </p>

        <script>
            var jobbAnim = 1;
            var speed = 1;
            var balAnim = 0;



            function jobbra() {

          if ( jobbAnim < 1300){
              var jobbAnim = jobbAnim + speed;
          }
            document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.marginLeft = jobbAnim + "px";

           }



            function balra() {
            document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.marginLeft = balAnim + "px";

            }
        </script>







</body>
</html>
```

Comment: remove that var from var jobbAnim inside if

Comment: oh man thx you're great. Any idea how can I make this work until 1300px wiht just one button click? Thanks

Comment: add up the clientWidth and style.margin of the div to matchup with the 1300px

Comment: could show me how? I don't understand.

Comment: I have added an answer to the question, hopes it will solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Hopes this solves the issue

```js
var jobbAnim = 1;
var speed = 10;
var balAnim = 0;
var max = 80; // 1300 here.
function jobbra () {
    var ilonakep = document.getElementById("ilonakep");
    if (ilonakep.clientWidth + parseInt(ilonakep.style.marginLeft) < max || ilonakep.style.marginLeft == '') {
        jobbAnim = jobbAnim + speed;
        ilonakep.style.marginLeft = jobbAnim + "px";
    } else console.log(max+' reached');
}
function balra () {
    document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.marginLeft = balAnim + "px";
    jobbAnim = 0;
}
```

```css
#ilonakep {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="ilonakep">
    <img src="/img/ilona.jpg" alt="ilona">
</div>
<p id="gombok">
    <button onclick="balra()">Balra</button>
    <button onclick="jobbra()">Jobbra</button>
</p>
```

Comment: This one doesn't work for me. I think I have to make a For loop somehow until 1300px. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I have edited the answer and hope this will be working for you.

Comment: I you want to move the entire div until 1300px , then remove that `ilonakep.clientWidth +` from the code.

Comment: if (jobbAnim < 400) {
                jobbAnim = jobbAnim + speed;
            }


            document.getElementById("ilonakep").style.marginLeft = jobbAnim + "px";
            window.requestAnimationFrame(jobbra);

        }

this works but I can't go back with the picture to it's starting point.

Comment: do you want to reset the image to starting position when you reach 1300px? or by hitting on "balra" button?

Comment: by hitting balra button and now it's 400 px because the image now in a div container.